# Must restart pulseaudio to get headphone working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04. After boot and get the desktop, I plug in my headphone. But no sound, unless I restart pulseaudio by `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio -D`.

How to avoid typing the command? Since I always plug in the headphone after getting the desktop. It's surely frustrating to retype the command everyday. I remember this issue doesn't happen if I plug in the headphone before my PC boots.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by removing pulseaudio and stick with alsa. Firefox seems to require pulseaudio to output sound, so I use Chrome instead.

For sound volume applet I use volumeicon and it seems working well.

UPDATE: I can use apulse to run Firefox.

UPDATE: I don't find this issue (yet?) in Debian 10, I guess it's the update in new kernel (4.19)